# Gradle - Incremental build support for a task

Tags: gradle, swagger, openapi

I am using some task ([Swagger codegen Gradle plugin](https://github.com/int128/gradle-swagger-generator-plugin) & [OpenAPI Style Validator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-style-validator)) in my Gradle build that do not support it seems the incremental build feature.

Googling a bit (and checking the Gradle doc) I understood that it seems possible to extend the tasks to add some properties, so I gave it a try, but unfortunately it does not seem to work.
Here's the `build.gradle` extension I added:

```
swaggerSources {
    jaxrsServer {
        inputFile = file('path/to/spec.yaml')
        code {
            language = 'jaxrs'
            library = 'jersey2'
            outputDir = file('build/generated/sources/swagger')
            templateDir = file('path/to/templates')
        }
    }
    jaxrsClient {
        inputFile = file('path/to/spec.yaml')
        code {
            language = 'java'
            library = 'jersey2'
            outputDir = file('build/generated/sources/swagger')
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(GenerateSwaggerCode) {
    inputs.file('path/to/spec.yaml')
    outputs.dir('build/generated/sources/swagger')
}

[...]

openAPIStyleValidator {
    inputFile = "$projectDir/path/to/spec.yaml"
    validateInfoLicense = false
}

tasks.withType(org.openapitools.openapistylevalidator.gradle.OpenAPIStyleValidatorTask) {
    inputs.file("$projectDir/path/to/spec.yaml")
}
```

And the (truncated) build output:

```
> Task :module:openAPIStyleValidator
Validating spec: /.../path/to/spec.yaml
[...]
> Task :module:resolveSwaggerTemplate NO-SOURCE
> Task :module:generateSwaggerCodeJaxrsClient
> Task :module:generateSwaggerCodeJaxrsServer
> Task :module:generateSwaggerCode NO-SOURCE
> Task :module:compileJava
```

Is the task extension wrong? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

`OpenAPIStyleValidatorTask` doesn't register itself so you'll have to create new task like this (Kotlin-based config):

```kotlin
create("validateApiDoc", OpenAPIStyleValidatorTask::class.java) {
    this.setValidateInfoLicense(false)
    this.setInputFile("$projectDir/src/jvmMain/resources/swagger-ui/api_documentation.yaml")
}
```

Comment: You mean, you can't use the task declaration as they mention in the project but create a new task instead?

Comment: @Xendar The plugin doesn't register this task at all. You can see it's not there if you run `gradle tasks --all`. Thus you have to register the task for `OpenAPIStyleValidatorTask` class.

Comment: Well, sorry but adding the `openAPIStyleValidator` closure in the `build.gradle` is enough to register the task, and it appears when running `gradle tasks --all`. Anyways, the purpose of the question of the incremental build